# Can Push Notifications be sent to users when they are signed out?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Can Push Notifications be sent to users after they log out of the PWA? I know the server would get the message and then forward it to the service worker but would it be able to then push the message to the user. We are trying to implement a messaging system for our users but didn't want to get in to deep before realizing we were going the wrong direction.

Comment: Be more specific please. If you want to send the PN to logged out user, it should be generic and logic can be handled at the backend whatever you are using.

Comment: I just wanted to know if it is even possible to send push notifications to a logged out user

Comment: yes you can. handle it at the backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I actually figured this out and hopefully I can provide some clarity to those that are confused about how push notifications works. So here's how the process works, this isn't going to be technical but rather the theory of how it works, also I'm using an npm package web-push to help implement this. On the front end you prompt the user if they would like to recieve push notifications from your site. If they accept you essentially create a unique endpoint for the user of your public Vapid Key. The public vapid key is created by web-push package(I'll link tutorials on how to do this). So the endpoint that is created is how the server knows where to send the push notification. So then you send that endpoint back to your server and save it in the db or whatever you want to do with it. So now if you want to send a push notification to that user you use webpush to generate a push to their service worker and use that unique endpoint as well so the server knows where to send it. The servers sends the message and the service worker picks it up and sends the push to the user. It doesn't matter if the user is signed in or not the endpoint that the server sends to is the browser not the users account. I think what confused me most about push notifications is how the server would know where to send the push notification to. I'll give an example to help illustrate better and hopefully make the process clearer. If I'm browsing on my computer with Google and I click on allow notifications from a site then an endpoint will be created that is unique to my computer and that browser. For simplicity sake lets say all notification endpoints are stored in an array in the database, so now my new endpoint get pushed to that array and stored in the db. Now I close google open up firefox and go to the same site. I now allow notifications for the same site with firefox. That endpoint gets created and pushed to that array in the db and saved in the db. Now the owner of the site wants to send a notification out to everyone that is subscribed to push notifications. Lets say he loops over every endpoint in his array of saved enpoints and sends a message to each one of them. I will get one notification from firefox and one from google. So again push notifications are linked and sent to the browser not the user. I thought that if you allowed notifications then the push notification would be sent to wherever you are logged in but nope it's sent to whichever browser you allowed push notifications from. A lack of understanding on my part but now it's much clearer how they work after I've implemented them

Comment: Actually your server does not send the messages. you just make a request to your messaging provider your client subscribet at. if you use google then its firebase cloud messaging (FCM). you use the generated url as a Web Push Protocol endpoint. so you make a request to that url and firebase sends that message to its client

Comment: are you using nodejs? the ´web-push´ package?